# Getting IS4 to issue refresh tokens

Tags: c#, identityserver4, refresh-token, asp.net-core-5.0

Ok, I am failing to get IS4 to issue a refresh token during authorization_code flow, even though I (believe) turned it on, and the client is requesting it by including `offline_access` in the scope. I add the IS4 using:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddPersistedGrantStore<PersistedGrantStore>()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddSigningCredential(loadedX509pfx);


// identity resources from another file:
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
    new IdentityResource[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    };
```

Client is defined as (I included everything except URLs for brevity):

```cs
    ClientId = "MyClientBlahBlah",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new("secretXX".Sha256()) }, 
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    RequireConsent = false,

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    AccessTokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(7).TotalSeconds,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(7).TotalSeconds,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(30).TotalSeconds,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(15).TotalSeconds,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    Enabled = true,
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
    },
    RequirePkce = false,
...
```

However, when the request comes via this request:
`GET /connect/authorize?client_id=MyClientBlahBlah&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=<targeturl>`

and the user logs in, the redirect URL is called only with authorization code:

[image: querystrings]

There is no mention of refresh token anywhere. When I check the grant persistence store, the record was created (though its set to expire in 5 mins), however, again, the `Data` JSON in the record of store does not contain any mention of the refresh and there is no additional record being created for the subject.

```json
{
    "CreationTime" : "2022-03-28T15:56:26Z",
    "Lifetime" : 300,
    "ClientId" : "MyClientBlahBlah",
    "Subject" : {...} <full json of claims, which is ok>
    "IsOpenId" : true,
    "RequestedScopes" : [
        "0" : "opened",
        "1" : "profile",
        "2" : "offline_access"
    ],
    "RedirectUri" : "targetURL",
    "Nonce" : null,
    "StateHash" : "d8EeV5-CyXT_-vbd8gRcRA",
    "WasConsentShown" :false,
    "SessionId" : "8DBD74DF791AD6C04FCCB78A3CF57C6E",
    "CodeChallenge" : "",
    "CodeChallengeMethod" : null,
    "Description" : null,
    "Properties" : { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what have I forgotten to include? I can't seem to find any help with documentation, most people have this problem when they forget to include `offline_access` in `scope`, which is not the case here.

Comment: Tore Nestenius's answer inspire me, and [I found this blogs](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2020/01/13/making-api-calls-using-the-access-token-and-refresh-token-from-an-aspnet-core-authentication-handler.html), I think it will useful to op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens (ID/Access/Refresh) are not meant be included in this request:

```
GET /connect/authorize?client_id=MyClientBlahBlah&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=<targeturl>
```

Instead the OpenIDConnect handler in ASP.NET Core will after receiving the authorization code, ask for the tokens in a separate request between ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer. A request not visible to the user/browser.

Using the code below you can check what tokens that you actually have received:

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");

string refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

string tokenType = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("token_type");         

string accessTokenExpire = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
```

Comment: Ah, so this all happens in the backchannel between client and oauth server, so I do not see it in the local stack. Gotcha. ok, let me just check something before accepting, this should probably show up in verbose logs...

Comment: Ok, all is well now. The refresh tokens are flowing in the backchannel, the bug was in the persisted storage (key was not properly marked).

Comment: Great! glad we solved your problem!